# Why do I need to flush() after remove() and before persist() in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following code:

```php
//Delete old existing file(s)
$files = $record->getFiles();

foreach ($files as $file) {
   $em->remove($file);
}

$em->flush();

$link = $record->getLink() ? $record->getLink() : new Link();
$link->setRecord($record);
$link->setUrl($metaData['location']);

$em->persist($link);

$em->flush();
```

I need to call the first `flush()` or else the `$file` entities are not deleted..why won't they be deleted by just using the second `flush()`?

For reference, here is the relationship definition of `Record`:

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Link
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Link", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="record")
 */
private $link;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\File
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\File", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="record")
 */
private $files;
```

Also, this code using a single flush() works fine (it's deleting a OneOnOne Entity instead of a OneToMany):

```
 //Delete old existing link
 $link = $record->getLink();
 if ($link) {
      $em->remove($link);
 }

 $file = $record->getFile() ? $record->getFile() : new File();
 $file->setRecord($record);

 $em->persist($file);

 $em->flush();
```

Comment: What about `orphanRemoval=true` on the `$files` property ?
Then you have a Files `Collection` that you can reset if needed on `Record` entity flush

Comment: The orphan doesn't work, the problem lies with the 'cascade={"persist"}' on files. I'll do some more debugging and see if I can figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found two ways of making my code work, which take two different approaches:

## First scenario: do not set any cascading logic in the Entity and process all operations manually.

**Record Entity**

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Link
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Link", mappedBy="record")
 */
private $link;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\File
 *
 * ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\File", mappedBy="record")
 */
private $files;
```

**Controller**

```
//Delete old existing file(s)
$files = $record->getFiles();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileService->deleteFile($file);
    //Remove the *owning* entity of the relationship
    $em->remove($file);
}

$em->flush();
$em->clear();

//We need to call clear() to remove all existing references of files 
//from the $record entity. Get the record again after this.
$record = $this->getRecordRepository()->findActive($id);

$link = $record->getLink() ? $record->getLink() : new Link();
$link->setRecord($record);
$link->setUrl($metaData['location']);

$em->persist($link);
$record->setType(Record::TYPE_LINK);

$em->flush();
```

## Second scenario: approach all DB operations from the `$record` perspective, and let the `cascade` and `orphanRemoval` do the rest

**Record Entity**

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Link
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Link", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="record", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $link;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\File
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\File", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, mappedBy="record", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $files;
```

**Controller**

```
//Delete old existing file(s)
$files = $record->getFiles();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $fileService->deleteFile($file);
    $record->removeFile($file);
}

$link = $record->getLink() ? $record->getLink() : new Link();
$link->setRecord($record);
$link->setUrl($metaData['location']);

$em->persist($link);
$record->setType(Record::TYPE_LINK);

$em->flush();
```

I personally favor the second approach, which needs less PHP code is more readable.

I'll leave this answer open for any comments/tips and close it this week.

Answer (score 1):

The `cascade` parameter has a options: 'remove', 'persist', 'refresh', 'merge', and 'detach'.

Treat them as flags so you can write:

```
cascade={"persist","remove"}
```

or even:

```
cascade={"all"}
```

Maybe this helps ...